# using filter in a nested array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to have an array that return certain property base on the checked property.

```
const data = [
      {
        "param": "type",
        "id": 6,
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Collect",
            "filterKey": "collect",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Redeem",
            "filterKey": "redeem",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "param": "country",
        "id": 5,
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Malaysia",
            "filterKey": "my",
            "checked": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Singapore",
            "filterKey": "sg",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Why my code below doesn't work? It's a function I use for my check or uncheck event

```
const checkedKeys = data.map(o => {
        return o.data.filter(o2 => {
          return o2.checked === true
        }).filterKey
    })
```

I expect to get `['my', 'redeem']` for above case.

Comment: Whats your expected result ? What is `data` in your code ?

Comment: @klugjo is the first block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with *array.protoype.concat*, *array.protoype.filter*, *array.protoype.map* and *spread* operator of ES6:

```js
var data = [ { "param": "type", "id": 6, "data": [{"name": "Collect", "filterKey": "collect", "checked": false }, {"name": "Redeem", "filterKey": "redeem", "checked": true }]}, {"param": "country","id": 5,"data": [{"name": "Malaysia","filterKey": "my","checked": true}, {"name": "Singapore","filterKey": "sg","checked": false}]}];

var result = [].concat(...data.map(o => o.data)).filter(d => d.checked).map(d => d.filterKey);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why my code below doesn't work? It's a function I use for my check or
>   uncheck event

Because `filter` returns an *array* and that *array* won't have `filterKey` property.

Use `reduce`, `filter` and `map`

```
var output = data.reduce( ( a, b ) => //use reduce to accumulate all filtered values
            a.concat( b.data.filter( o2 =>  //filter by checked
                o2.checked ).map( o3 =>   // map to get only the filterKey property
                   o3.filterKey ) ) , []); //[] is the initial value of accumulator
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  {
    "param": "type",
    "id": 6,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Collect",
        "filterKey": "collect",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Redeem",
        "filterKey": "redeem",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "param": "country",
    "id": 5,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Malaysia",
        "filterKey": "my",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Singapore",
        "filterKey": "sg",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  }
];

var output = data.reduce( (a,b) => a.concat( b.data.filter( o2 => o2.checked ).map( o3 => o3.filterKey ) ) , []) ;

console.log( output );
```

Comment: the concat confused me, what's that for?

Comment: `concat` will concatenate output of one `filter` to another, since your filtering inner arrays.

Comment: This is an opinionated comment, but this is where ES6 reduces readability.  Though nicely indented, I prefer using `() => {}` pattern and return manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this as well.

#### Logic

- Create a temporary array. (*`acc` in below example*).
- Loop over `data` and in turn loop over `data[i].data`
- Check if `checked` is true, push `filterKey` value to `acc`.

**ES5 Version:**

```js
var data = [ { "param": "type", "id": 6, "data": [ { "name": "Collect", "filterKey": "collect", "checked": false }, { "name": "Redeem", "filterKey": "redeem", "checked": true } ] }, { "param": "country", "id": 5, "data": [ { "name": "Malaysia", "filterKey": "my", "checked": true }, { "name": "Singapore", "filterKey": "sg", "checked": false } ] } ];

var result = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  obj.data.forEach(function(curObj) {
    if (curObj.checked) {
      acc.push(curObj.filterKey)
    }
  })
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result);
```

**ES6 Version:**

```js
var data = [ { "param": "type", "id": 6, "data": [ { "name": "Collect", "filterKey": "collect", "checked": false }, { "name": "Redeem", "filterKey": "redeem", "checked": true } ] }, { "param": "country", "id": 5, "data": [ { "name": "Malaysia", "filterKey": "my", "checked": true }, { "name": "Singapore", "filterKey": "sg", "checked": false } ] } ];

var result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  obj.data.forEach(({filterKey, checked}) => {
    checked && acc.push(filterKey)
  })
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner way to achieve same thing.

```js
data.map(o => o.data) //gets dataArray
  .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), []) //concats array
  .filter(o => o.checked) // filters for checked= true
  .map(o => o.filterKey) //returns filter key
```

Comment: Works, simple, well explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using simple javascript too which is seemingly easy to understand and will you to edit easily for future changes. Although the complexity based on time and space is same when you use ECMA script or pure javascript. Just depends on shorthand codes.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "param": "type",
    "id": 6,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Collect",
        "filterKey": "collect",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Redeem",
        "filterKey": "redeem",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "param": "country",
    "id": 5,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Malaysia",
        "filterKey": "my",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Singapore",
        "filterKey": "sg",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  }
];

var checkedKeys = [];

data.forEach((dataItem)=>{
  dataItem.data.forEach((innerData)=>{
      if(innerData.checked){
        checkedKeys.push(innerData.filterKey);
      }
  });
});
console.log(checkedKeys)
```

Comment: I use filter because in data the checked value can be false, if that's so remove the key from checkKeys array

Comment: The `checkKeys` array will always have keys that has `checked` property true in above code.

Comment: that's the problem,I think you're missing to pull the element out of the array if the checked became false from true.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map( // iterate over the top level list
  x => (
    x.data.filter( // select only the checked items from the nested `data` list
      y => y.checked
    ).map( // select only the `filterKey` property of the filtered items
      y => y.filterKey
    )
  )
).reduce( // flatten the end-result [['redeem'],['my']] -> ['redeem', 'my]
  (acc, prev) => acc.concat(prev), []
);
```